# Data Export stuck in PM Environment after a month

Tags: data-export, queue

one of our users went into the Data Export tool, selected a number of objects(not sure which ones) and clicked "export now." That was almost a month ago. The job doesn't appear in the "Scheduled Jobs" list and the Data Export screen says: "A data export is currently in progress for your organization."

I see nothing in the Apex Queue nor in any queue.

Is there any way to track this job down?

Comment: You don't export classes, you export objects. Is that what you mean? If an export happens to be stuck, you need to contact Support. There's nowhere in the system that you have access to that will tell you anything more useful than "processing."

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I meant objects, but inadvertently said classes. I edited the original question. I didn't think there was a way to track this down, but I wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I meant to answer this sooner for closure: the job ended up clearing itself out after a few more days. This situation hasn't recurred.